# Cache values get overwritten?

Tags: c#

I have implemented caching in my class library and am having a problem. What i do is that i pass a value that i need to read from XML file and it will return the nodes and the values back. I have used dictionary to store the childnodes as key value pair. Please see my xml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
    <Test1>
      <CompanyDetails>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Address1>Add1</Address1>
        <Address2>Add2</Address2>
        <Address3>Add3</Address3>
        <Phone>1111</Phone>
      </CompanyDetails>
      <Email>
        <Contact>contact@test1.com</Contact>
      </Email>
      <AdminUsers>
        <User1>user1</User1>
        <User2>user2</User2>
      </AdminUsers>
    </Test1>
  </Settings>
```

Please see my code below

```
using System.Web;
public Dictionary<string, string> GetDataFromSettings(string strValues)
{
Dictionary<string, string> dictValus = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    string xmlFilePath = "D:\\Test.xml";
    xmlDoc.Load(xmlFilePath);
    if (!(xmlDoc == null))
    {
        string[] splitValues = strValues.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        if (splitValues.Length > 1)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> strDictValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string strName in splitValues)
            {
                if (HttpRuntime.Cache[strName.Trim()] == null)
                {
                    strDictValues.Clear();
                    XmlNodeList xmlList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Settings/Test1/" + strName.Trim());

                    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlList)
                    {
                        if (node.FirstChild.Name.ToString() != node.LastChild.Name.ToString())
                        {
                            foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
                            {
                                strDictValues.Add(strName.Trim() + "." + childNode.LocalName, childNode.InnerText);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strDictValues.Add(strName.Trim() + "." + node.FirstChild.LocalName, node.InnerText);
                        }
                    }
                    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(strName.Trim(), strDictValues,new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(xmlFilePath));
                }
                else
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> tmpDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    tmpDict = (Dictionary<string, string>)HttpRuntime.Cache[strName.Trim()];

                    foreach (var tmpVal in tmpDict)
                    {
                        strDictValues.Add(tmpVal.Key, tmpVal.Value);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var tmpStrDict in strDictValues)
                {
                    dictValus.Add(tmpStrDict.Key, tmpStrDict.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dictValus;
   }
```

In my xml example above, i will pass the string as "CompanyDetails,Email" to the function above and i split the string and then store the values each string seperately in the cache. When i run for the first time, the values under the "CompanyDetails" is stored in the cache named "CompanyDetails" and when it goes for the node "Email", cache["CompanyDetails"] is getting overwritten and also cache["Email"] is created and both of them has the same values. This is not correct. I am not able to find the reason why it's happening.

Thanks,
Jollyguy

Comment: Why do you do `splitValues.Length > 1` instead of `splitValues.Length > 0`?  Checking `> 1` means you will not cache values for a single key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, when you are building the cache, you clear and reuse the dictionary rather than create a new dictionary for each `strName` key.  Since the dictionary you clear is the dictionary that was added to the cache -- which does *not* copy the dictionary, but only save a reference to it -- you wipe out your previous values.

Try the following (note I refactored a slightly lower level version for ease of debugging, and eliminated redundant calls to "strName.Trim()"):

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetDataFromSettings(TextReader reader, string xmlFilePath, string strValues)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(reader);
        return GetDataFromSettings(xmlDoc, xmlFilePath, strValues);
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetDataFromSettings(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string xmlFilePath, string strValues)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dictValus = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (!(xmlDoc == null))
        {
            string[] splitValues = strValues.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            if (splitValues.Length > 1)
            {
                foreach (string strName in splitValues.Select((s) => s.Trim()))
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> strDictValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    if (HttpRuntime.Cache[strName] == null)
                    {
                        XmlNodeList xmlList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Settings/Test1/" + strName);

                        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlList)
                        {
                            if (node.FirstChild.Name.ToString() != node.LastChild.Name.ToString())
                            {
                                foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
                                {
                                    strDictValues.Add(strName + "." + childNode.LocalName, childNode.InnerText);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                strDictValues.Add(strName + "." + node.FirstChild.LocalName, node.InnerText);
                            }
                        }
                        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(strName, strDictValues, new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(xmlFilePath));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var tmpDict = (Dictionary<string, string>)HttpRuntime.Cache[strName];
                        foreach (var tmpVal in tmpDict)
                        {
                            strDictValues.Add(tmpVal.Key, tmpVal.Value);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var tmpStrDict in strDictValues)
                    {
                        dictValus.Add(tmpStrDict.Key, tmpStrDict.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dictValus;
    }
```